# Is there something special with maven get: gt-map 26.5

Tags: geotools, maven

I can't download gt-map ver 26.5. it works fine with gt-process and others.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>26.5</geotools.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-map</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I get this error:
Missing artifact org.geotools:gt-map:jar:26.5

Answer (score 1):

That would be because there is no `gt-map` module in the GeoTools code base. Did you perhaps mean `gt-main` ?

### Update

To find a specific class in GeoTools the easiest way is to search the code base:

```
modules git:(main) find . -name 'MapContent.java'
./library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/map/MapContent.java
```

Or if for some reason you don't have the GeoTools code on your hard drive use the GitHub search:

```
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/search?q=MapContent
```

Then look in the `pom.xml` file to see what the module name is:

```
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!--     Module Description                                      -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-render</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Render</name>
```

Comment: Sorry, but how shall I set up my dependencies to get access to: org.geotools.map
Class MapContent
   (See https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/map/MapContent.html)